# Quelle est la différence entre "ce que" et "celui/celle que"?

Tags: démonstratifs

Dans la phrase « Il n'y a que cinquante et une cartes dans ce jeu, où est _ manque ? », pourquoi dit-on « celle qui » et pas « ce qui » ?

Comment: Parce qu'on parle d'un mot de genre feminin ?

Comment: @oldergod celle est la forme féminin de ce?

Comment: Je pensais mais en fait, il semblerait que non : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ce#Vocabulaire_apparent.C3.A9_par_le_sens Voir "Vocabulaire apparenté par le sens"

Comment: @BrightFuture Non, *celle* est le féminin de *celui*. Et *ceux/celles* sont les pluriels.

Answer (score 3):

On pourrait dire *où est ce qui manque ?* si on ne référait pas à *la* carte manquante. Le *ce* dans ce cas renverrait plutôt à un [collectif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_collectif)/[massif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_%28grammaire%29#Noms_massifs_et_noms_comptables).